# Notificação ao clicar no botão

Tags: android

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),"M_CH_ID");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notificacao)
            .setContentTitle("RPfm 105.3")
            .setContentText("Ao Vivo")
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notifyManager = (NotificationManager) Objects.<FragmentActivity>requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if(notifyManager != null) {
        notifyManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
```

Esse codigo estava funcionando ante de atualizar o android studio.
Alguém sab oq pode ser.
No Log não da erro de nda, e já debuguei, ele chama o metodo, mais não exibe a notificação.

Comment: Qual API esta utilizando ?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 27